# How to execute a file by providing parameters from another process

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

How do I run/execute an instance of a node file by providing some parameters from another programs by knowing the location and content of file.

When I add a device from my web application which also run on node (adonis js), it create a device with provided params like, device_name, type, lat, lng etc. when device successful added, an instance or copy of the following code should starts automatically with provided params when device was added.

file which need to started with given parameters

```
   // c:/device/test.js

var mqtt = require('mqtt');
function UserModule() {
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');
client.on('connect', function () {
    let latitude = 777
    let lngitude = 999
setInterval(function() {
    let device_data = {
        'device_name':'{params.devcie_name}',
        'topic_topic':'MyProject/{params.type_of_device}/{params.user_id}/{params.topic_name}',
        'type':'GPS', 
        'data':{
            'lat':'35.'+latitude++,
            'lng':'-74.'+lngitude++,
            'alt':22,
            'acc':25.10101,
            'name': 'my car2',
            'type': 'car'
        },
        'status': 'OK'
    }
client.publish(device_data.topic_topic, JSON.stringify(device_data));
console.log('data published for', device_data.device_name);
}, 1000);
});
}
module.exports = UserModule;
```

controller for adding device

```
//app/controllers/http/devicecontroller.js

async store({ params, request, response, view, session, auth }) {
    try {
        const deviceData = request.only(['cat_id', 'device_name', 'type', 'device_type_id'])
        deviceData.device_owner_id = auth.current.user.id
        deviceData.is_deleted = 0
        deviceData.is_active = 1
        const device = new Device();

        let rules = Config.get('rules.device')
        let messages = Config.get('messages.device')

        const validation = await validate(deviceData, rules, messages)
        if (validation.fails()) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(validation.messages()))
            session.flash({ type: 'danger', message: validation.messages()[0].message })
            return response.redirect('back')
        }

        let dev = await deviceService.addDevice(deviceData);
        session.flash({ type: 'success', message: 'Device added successfully' })
//here to run a code which execute that file
//sudo-code

File f  = new File('c:/device/test.js')
let content  = await f.readAll()

content = string.format(content, params1, params2, params3..)

f.content = content;
f.eecute()


        return response.redirect('/dashboard/device-manage')
    } catch (error) {
        session.flash({ type: 'danger', message: error.message })
        return response.redirect('back')
    }
}
```

Ho I execute the code every time when I add a device, every time with new parameters, means executing same file with new instance with new parameters.

Comment: Do you want to `execute` it as a new separate process? Or do you just want to call it like a function in the same process?

Comment: a seperate process, may be by clicking another button, I should stop/kill that process

Comment: @TKoL I have also updated the question with sudo code, which I need to execute as

Answer (score 1):

To start a new process, use the node package child_process

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options

To send messages to that child_process, use child_process.fork

```
const cp = require('child_process');
const n = cp.fork(`${__dirname}/sub.js`);

n.on('message', (m) => {
  console.log('PARENT got message:', m);
});

// Causes the child to print: CHILD got message: { hello: 'world' }
n.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback